# Pointer is Affected on Function Call Where it Shouldn't Be

Tags: c, function, pointers

I am calling the function below, which calculates a value given in the passed in variables. However, when the function (`calculate_distance`) runs, the data contained in the variable (`loc_ptr`) that is passed into the function seems to change.

I have stepped through the code to find that the variable `loc_ptr` is affected on the function call, rather than inside the function itself.

The function is being called in a while loop. The first iteration of the while loop calculates correctly, it is only on subsequent iterations that the problem seems to occur.

_Note: location is a typedef'ed struct containing char *name, double latitude, double longitude. `options` is an array of doubles._

```
double calculate_distance(location from, location to) {
    return to.latitude - from.latitude;
}

main() {
    location current_location = {"Plymouth", 50.378565, -4.134339};
    location locations[3] = {{"Padstow", 50.5384, -4.9378}, 
                            {"Newquay", 50.412, -5.0757}, 
                            {"Boscastle", 50.684, -4.6929}};

    // create a pointer to an array of locations.
    location* loc_ptr;
    loc_ptr = &locations[0];

    double options[3];
    int i = 0;
    int position = 3;

    while (i < position) {
        // calculate the distance between the current and other locations
        options[position] = calculate_distance(current_location,
                                                loc_ptr[position]);
        position--;
    }
    // handle the rest of the algorithm
}
```

*Note: The code is part of a larger algorithm, it's cut short as it would be quite long. After the while loop finishes, the `loc_ptr` array is rebuilt to remove one of the elements.*

Comment: what is `locations`? How is it defined/allocated?

Comment: Where and how options[] is defined?

Comment: @jswolf19, @pmod: I added a definition. @Jens: It was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Your example code does...

- not compile for a variety of reasons, typos, and omissions; and
- does not contain any obvious error that would explain the behaviour you observed.

It is also being nonsensical (`locations` being absent, for example). That means that either you're seeing ghosts, or your example code doesn't show what the real code really does (and does no longer contain the bug in question because you cut it away).

Either way, nobody could really tell because you did not give enough information.

Try [this little debugging technique](http://dev.rootdirectory.de/trac.fcgi/wiki/SolarsMachete).

**Edit:** After you updated your question, at least your example code compiles properly (after I added the typedef). It accesses undefined memory on the first loop (because an array defined as e.g. `options[3]` does have elements `options[0] .. options[2]`, but not `options[3]`). What does **not** happen is that the value of `loc_ptr` changes in any way (as I verified using a debugger). So either you're still seeing ghosts, or your example code does not exhibit the problem you are having (making it worthless as an example). My recommendation (see above link) remains.

Answer (score 2):

Stack corruption? check sizes of options[] locations[] arrays. It's also good to use asserts to avoid running out of bounds.

So, now I see problem with indexes. locations[] array has 3 elements, but you access the forth during the first loop (loc_ptr[position] -> loc_ptr[3]), the same with options[].

Answer (score 1):

Form the code, it seems that the first call in on the not existing element locations[3]. Is that significant?

Answer (score 0):

Your can't access location[3] since the highest index in that array is 2. You probably wanted:

```
for (int i = 2;i >= 0;i--) 
    options[i] = calculate_distance(current_location, locations[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be at

```
loc_ptr = &locations[0];
```

`locations` seems to be an array of `location` elements. Getting the address of the first element of this array will give you a pointer to this element.

Why not just do `locations[position]` instead of creating the extra `loc_ptr` to hold the same information? I'm pretty sure the issue is with the content of `locations` - which is also not in the scope of your code snippet.